# problems doing simple POST

Tags: javascript, http, post

I'm trying to do a simple HTTP post from Javascript.  In the following code, the breakpoint on line 24 hits but the one on 25 does not.  Line 26 is also not processed (I added it just to try something else).  The server is also not getting the connection, though I can type that URL manually in my browser and see the connection.  I also do see the console output from line 22, so I know that function is firing.

[image]

```
subscription.then(function() {
    console.log("connected to server");
    //request back load of data
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/getData", true);
    xhttp.send();
    $.post("http://localhost:8000/getData")
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see any denies in the browser console ? Is localhost:8000 the same host/port combination your javascript is running on ? If not you might have a cross origin problem.

Comment: If it is a getData, why you're using POST?

Comment: It's expected to have some output in the browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe You've forgot to create XMLHttpRequest object?

```
subscription.then(function() {
    console.log("connected to server");
    //request back load of data
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // creating request object
    request.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/getData", true);
    request.send();
});
```

Comment: That was the exact problem! :|

Comment: why would I not get an error telling me xhttp was undefined or something?

Comment: seems like You've xhttp variable in global scope

Comment: not sure where, but makes sense.  I'll accept when the timer runs out